# Property Sheet displays too large

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a shipping piece of software, that uses property sheets for Tools/Options. For almost all my customers everything is perfect, but for just 2 or 3 the property sheets appear as though the dialog units are too large. The fonts, edit boxes, and all controls are about 1/3 too large, but with the same 0,0 origin. Even so, the containing dialog size is unchanged, so the result is that some of the controls on the right and bottom are either clipped or not visible at all.

We only use property sheets in two places, and for customers with this problem, both instances are affected identically. This only happens with Property sheets, and not with normal dialogs.

The resources are defined in the `.rc` file like:

```
[DLG_PREF7 DIALOG  10, 91, 300, 179
STYLE DS_ABSALIGN | DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_3DLOOK | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Font"
FONT 8, "MS Sans Serif"
BEGIN
    LTEXT           "Fixed-width font",79,7,7,119,12,SS_CENTERIMAGE
    COMBOBOX        80,131,7,126,300,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_SORT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP
    LTEXT           "Proportional font",87,7,25,119,12,SS_CENTERIMAGE
    COMBOBOX        88,131,25,126,300,CBS_DROPDOWNLIST | CBS_SORT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP
    LTEXT           "Font size",-1,7,43,119,12,SS_CENTERIMAGE
    EDITTEXT        705,131,43,20,12,ES_RIGHT | ES_NUMBER | WS_GROUP | WS_TABSTOP 
END][1]
```

A picture is worth a thousand words, but I'm not sure if my picture 'took'. If not, imagine if you could have used ctrl/mouse-wheel to increase the size of the contents of just this dialog.

I am stumped. Does anyone have an idea of what might be happening?

Comment: [High DPI Desktop Application Development on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows).

Comment: [`DS_SHELLFONT` and `DIALOGEX` may help](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050208-00/?p=36503).

Comment: IInspectable, thanks for the suggestion about high DPI, but I don't think that is the issue.  The users aren't changing their resolution, or switching to screens with a different resolution. The page you referred me to ties DPI to the text scaling factior, and our software runs correctly at 100% and 125%, although the differeces we see does seem to be a round number, like 75%.

Comment: I'll try Raymond's suggestions, although I'm unclear why this issue happens on such a small number of machines.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your comments. The problem is now solved. As it turns out, the issue was my explicit use of the font "MS Sans Serif". Apparently, some foreign systems don't include this font, and when this occurs Windows substitutes the system font, which doesn't have the same font characteristics, and doesn't fit the defined size of the dialog.

Comment: The solution was to substitute "Microsoft Sans Serif", and all is now well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your comments. The problem is now solved. As it turns out, the issue was my explicit use of the font "MS Sans Serif". Apparently, some foreign systems don't include this font, and when this occurs Windows substitutes the system font, which doesn't have the same font characteristics, and doesn't fit the defined size of the dialog.

The solution was to substitute "Microsoft Sans Serif", and all is now well.